# How to put blur effect on particular area of background image?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image. Inside of div, there is centred div with a text. To make text more comfortable to read I want to blur the background image of parent div in this particular area

I wanted to use backdrop-filter: blur on text div, but realized that it is not supported by firefox yet

```css
.parent {
  background: url(...);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px) ---unfortunately not supported in firefox
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Any other ways to blur the backside area?

Comment: Do u want the image blur effect for text visible?

Comment: Yeah, blur the image ONLY where text lays on @Manikandan2811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

backdrop-filter is hardly supported , only with   [Webkit Nightlies](https://webkit.org/build-archives/) but filter:blur(10px); becomes much more supported.

You may try an alternative with filter and use background-attachement to create 2 pieces on top of each other , a smaller piece blured.

example :

```css
body {
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* prepare for the blurry piece to add */
  background-size: 100vw auto;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

p:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(10px);
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100vw auto;
}

p {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20vh 10vh;
  /*background:white; if needed */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vw);
  border:solid 1px;
  border-radius:1em;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 2px
}
```

```html
<p> is this backdrop alternative do the job ? </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better compare to backdrop filter..

**css**

```
.parent{    
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.child{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("photographer.jpg");

  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  height: 100%; 
  background-position: cente`enter code here`r;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


.child {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);`enter code here`
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); 
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```